# How to make GetKafka always read from latest offset in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm using [`GetKafka`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-0-8-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.GetKafka/index.html) of Apache Nifi to read message.

When I **restart** the processor, I'd like to make it always read from the latest off-set, instead the off-set this group committed.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GetKafka` processor is *deprecated*. Please use the [`ConsumeKafka`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-kafka-0-9-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafka/) processor instead. This processor has a setting called **Offset Reset** which accepts *earliest*, *latest*, and *none* as options. *Latest* should do what you need.

*Note:* if you still need `GetKafka` to work with a Kafka 0.8 instance, there is an option for **Auto Offset Reset** with the possible values *smallest* and *largest*.

Comment: To add to Andy's comment... even with ConsumeKafka, the Offset Reset is used when there is no offset for the current consumer group, so in the case you had runt he processor before, stopped it, and started again, it will not be used because it would start from the offset from before. You need to change the consumer group id to start over from earliest.